# Ready-to-use VMware guest operating systems

Tags: vmware, appliance

Do you know of any good preconfigured VM sites available out there? Mostly VMware. I'm looking for sites such as [this one](http://www.osboxes.org/vmware-images/).

Google didn't return much. Maybe I'm not using the right terms in my searches.

Answer (score 1):

The acknowledged term is `virtual appliance`. Have you checked [VmWare's marketplace](https://solutionexchange.vmware.com/store/category_groups/virtual-appliances)?

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded a preconfigured Mint Mate guest for VMware Player to my OneDrive. Have a **[look here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&resid=475a0a48ca6d4035%212604&app=WordPdf)**.